# Angular client post request for Spring boot REST Api

Tags: java, angular

I need your help for the following.
I have client application using Angular 8 and Spring Boot REST Api:

I'm calling the REST Api below :

```
 public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'services/uaa-nghiapt/api/register-orders';
  /**
   * This method call rest server for update active as TRUE
   * @param key id of register order
   * @param code active code
   */
  activate(key:string,code:string):Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    return this.http.post<HttpResponse<string>>(this.resourceUrl+"/activate",{key:key,code:code});
  }
```

And this is rest api code :

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/register-orders/activate")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerActivate(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.registerOrderService.registerActivate(payload));
    }
```

I am getting an error as shown below :

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js:1644:51)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:24730:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:60)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:194:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:497:34)
    at invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1692:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1729:21)"
```

Now I want get string type is response of Api.

please help me .

thank for watching

Comment: Please include the full error text here instead of pasting in the image. It is currently not possible to actually see the existing error message in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `parse` the response or trying to `response.json()`.
These are failed because the Return type of your REST Api is String.
Remove parsing the response from the code.

Hope this will helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

You don't return json in spring boot, but a plain text. That's why it's giving you this error.
Try the following:

`http.post(url, body, {responseType: text'}`